# How to use an installed HttpResponseCache

Tags: android, caching, httpurlconnection, httpresponsecache

I've followed the [developers guide](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/http/HttpResponseCache.html) and I've installed an HttpResponseCache by including the following code in the onCreate() method of my application:

```
try {
  File httpCacheDir = new File(context.getCacheDir(), "http");
  long httpCacheSize = 10 * 1024 * 1024; // 10 MiB
  HttpResponseCache.install(httpCacheDir, httpCacheSize);
}   catch (IOException e) {
       Log.i(TAG, "HTTP response cache installation failed:" + e);      
}
```

Now, at some point I launch an activity in this application and fetch a URL using the following code:

```
URL url = new URL("http://www.android.com/");
HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
try {
  InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(urlConnection.getInputStream());
  readStream(in);
} finally {
  urlConnection.disconnect();
}
```

Do I have to do something when I fetch the URL to tell it to use the installed cache? Or will any activity launched inside this application automatically use it?

For example, in [this example code](http://practicaldroid.blogspot.com/2013/01/utilizing-http-response-cache.html) they call `connection.setUseCaches(true)`. Is that necessary?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The installed HttpResponseCache will be used by `HttpURLConnection` and `HttpsURLConnection` as long as you call `setUseCaches(true)` on the connection.

Also the response from the web server needs to be cacheable.

Comment: I have used HTTPClient for request. How I can use HttpResponseCatch here?

Comment: **setUseCaches(true)** is unnecessary